# How to create a son that will do exec of a program read by keyboard

Tags: c, system-calls

i'm trying to resolve this problem with C - system call. 
I want to create a son that will do exec of a program read by keyboard.. 
This is what I implemented so far..

```
void main(void) {

    char array[100];
    char character;
    char i = 0;
    do {
        character = getchar();
        array[i] = character;
        i++;
    }
    while (character != '\n');
    array[i-1] = '\0';

    pid_t  pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        printf ("error");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execvp(*array, argv) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
            printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
            exit(1);
        } 
        else {
            int  i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                printf("parent: %d\n", i);
                sleep(1);
            }
        exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with that? (don't pay attention to brackets..:D)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: *You* tell *us* what's wrong with it, then we try to help fix it.

Comment: I *will* pay attention to the brackets. :D

Comment: Why _son_, why not _daughter_?

Comment: `void main()`--> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

Some of the things wrong with that:

1. `while (character != '\n');` will either do nothing or get stuck forever.
2. You never declare `argv`, much less give it value before passing it as an argument to `execvp`.